# Oracle SQL to insert comma separated string into table

Tags: csv

I need to insert comma separated string into Oracle table column wise. CSV string may contain null or element can be enclosed in double quotes having comma between them. Please help.

I tried few ways but having issue with null values and comma between double quotes.